# Exception in Python Trace Module: "Charmap Can't Encode..."

Tags: python-3.x, trace, standard-library

I am using the python trace module in order to figure out why my program is exiting early.

However, there seems to be a bug with the trace module itself.

When i run `py -m trace -t src/main.py > temp/trace.txt` in powershell, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\trace.py", line 740, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\trace.py", line 728, in main
    t.runctx(code, globs, globs)
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\trace.py", line 450, in runctx
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "src/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from project_core.image_processing import *
  File "G:\My Drive\Swamynathan Lab Image Processing\ImageProcessingProjectLatestCodeWithGitVersionTracking\project\project_core\image_processing.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
    from . import polynomial
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\polynomial\__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
    from .polynomial import Polynomial
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\polynomial\polynomial.py", line 87, in <module>
    from ._polybase import ABCPolyBase
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\polynomial\_polybase.py", line 18, in <module>
    class ABCPolyBase(abc.ABC):
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\polynomial\_polybase.py", line 73, in ABCPolyBase
    "0": "⁰",
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\polynomial\_polybase.py", line 73, in ABCPolyBase
    "0": "⁰",
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\trace.py", line 575, in localtrace_trace
    print("%s(%d): %s" % (bname, lineno,
  File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2070' in position 32: character maps to <undefined>
```

Is there any straightforward way to fix this problem?

Comment: Your title is misleading, there's nothing about UTF-8 in that error message.  But you might be able to fix it by setting the environment variable PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 before running the program.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Title changed. Also your solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question was simple enough to answer in the comments.

Comment: No need to close it, it's still a question that could be useful to someone with the same problem. But the title's still wrong, it says "decode" but your error says "encode".

Comment: @Mark Ransom. Got it. But as a new-ish so member, what is the best way to manage a question if it was answered in the comments?

Comment: Does your question's first line *"I am using the python trace module in order to figure out why my program is exiting early.",* adds value to your main question?

Comment: The best way is to ask that the comment be rewritten as a proper answer.  No need to ask in your case, I'll do it on my own.  Your cleanup of the title is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the trace module is opening a file with the default encoding for your Python implementation.  On Windows this is often `cp1252` which you can see in the error dump.  CP1252 is incapable of encoding every possible Unicode character, so sometimes you'll run into this problem.

Python will use the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING` to override the default.  If you set it before you start Python to something that can encode all the Unicode characters such as `utf-8` or `utf-8-sig` it will eliminate the error.  Unfortunately this will affect all other text files opened by your program.